# Data provider with pom having source and test package

Tags: excel, apache-poi, testng, pom.xml

I have method with parameter in pom source page,1 created excel utility class for getRow count,getcellcount,getcell data and pom test package in which my method will execute  Can I use data provider with pom framework  I have parameter with method then how can I excute test case in pom test package

I have method with parameter in pom source page,1excel utility class for getRow count,getcellcount,getcell data and pom test package in which my method will execute  Can I use data provider with pom framework  I have parameter with method then how can I excute test case in pom test package